# Message "Failure: this commit cannot be built" in github

Tags: heroku, github, jenkins

I'm see build error messages ("Failure: This commit cannot be built") for each commit in github, yet I'm not aware that I have automated builds set up in github.

[image]

When I click on the "x" the browser attempts to go to the following link:
http://unconfigured-jenkins-location/job/testgithub/job/bitcoin-core/job/master/7/display/redirect
which fails with a 404.

I have a webhook set up for heroku but it is set up for manual deployments and the last time I kicked off a deployment was prior to many of these error messages.

Update: 
Here's a screenshot of the webhooks that are currently configured for the project:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you also have a jenkins service/hook configured on your repo.

Comment: There's one webhook configured (heroku - updated the question with the screenshot) and no services or installed integrations.

Comment: That could be an organization-wide webhook too.

Comment: Just checked and this repo isn't part of any organizations.

Comment: Try contacting GitHub support then. They'll be the ones able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just discovered that there was an external Jenkins instance that was pulling code from the repo and was pushing the build status back into github (was expecting that interaction to be read-only from github's perspective).

Answer (score 0):

It means build process attached to each commit. When it triggered build for that commit, due to some reason the build has been failed. Not necessarily due to this commit, it could be i/o or any other issue.

Comment: Small answers should go in comments section

Comment: Ok will do next time